# Powershell Remoting with local Administrator in Domain

Tags: powershell, domain, local, remoting

I would like to establish Powershell remote sessions to domain members by using their local administrator for authentication. Let's say I have a host called "server1" in the domain "test.local". If I connect with "test.local\myadmin" I can establish a remote session and it is just fine, but if I connect using "server1\Administrator" using the correct local admin password I get the error code 0x80090311. I read [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting/) that explains how to connect to a workgroup computer with local admin and to a domain computer with a domain account, but I couldn't find a similar article on how to connect to a domain computer with local admin.

Does someone know how to configure a domain computer to let other domain computer connect to it using the local admin account of the target computer?

Comment: Do the endpoints have a common authentication method?

Comment: Nope, they can't do Kerberos and don't have any other options. I think it needs to use WinRM via HTTPs. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Probably the only option given that scenario.